# Matlab: Random sample with replacement

Tags: matlab, replace, random

What is the best way to do random sample with replacement from dataset? I am using 316 * 34 as my dataset. I want to segment the data into **three** buckets but with replacement. Should I use the randperm because I need to make sure I keep the index intact where that index would be handy in identifying the label data. I am new to matlab I saw there are couple of random sample methods but they didn't look like its doing what I am looking for, its strange to think that something like doesn't exist in matlab, but I did the follwoing:

My issue is when I do this `row_idx = round(rand(1)*316)` sometimes I get zero, that leads to two questions

1. what should I do to avoid zeor?
2. What is the best way to do the random sample with replacement.

   ```
       shuffle_X = X(randperm(size(X,1)),:);
       lengthOf_shuffle_X = length(shuffle_X)
       number_of_rows_per_bucket = round(lengthOf_shuffle_X / 3)
       bucket_cell = cell(3,1)
       bag_matrix = []
       for k = 1:length(bucket_cell)
           for i = 1:number_of_rows_per_bucket
               row_idx = round(rand(1)*316)
               bag_matrix(i,:) = shuffle_X(row_idx,:)
           end
           bucket_cell{k} = bag_matrix
       end
   ```

I could do following:

```
            if row_idx == 0
                row_idx = round(rand(1)*316)
```

assuming random number will never give two zeros values in two consecutive rounds.

Answer (score 1):

`randi` is a good way to get integer indices for sampling with replacement. Assuming you want to fill three buckets with an equal number of samples, then you can write

```
data = rand(316,34); %# create some dummy data
number_of_data = size(data,1);
number_of_rows_per_bucket = 50;
bucket_cell = cell(1,3);

idx = randi([1,number_of_data],[number_of_rows_per_bucket,3]);

for iBucket = 1:3
   bucket_cell{iBucket} = data(idx(:,iBucket),:);
end
```

Comment: Not sure if you meant to type "with replacement" instead of "without replacement" I am looking for "with replacement"

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: Oops, I mis-typed. It's of course sampling with replacement.

Answer (score 1):

To the question: if you use `randperm` it will give you a draw order without replacement, since you can draw any item once.

If you use `randi` it draws you with replacement, that is you draw an item possibly many times.

If you want to "segment" a dataset, that usually means you split the dataset into three distinct sets. For that you use draw without replacement (you don't put the items back; use `randperm`). If you'd do it with replacement (using `randi`), it will be incredibly slow, since after some time the chance that you draw an item which you have not before is very low.
(Details in [coupon collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) ).

**If you need a segmentation that is a split**, you can just go over the elements and independently decide where to put it. (That is you choose a bucket for each item with replacement -- that is you put any chosen bucket back into the game.)

For that:

```
% if your data items are vectors say data = [1 1; 2 2; 3 3; 4 4]
num_data = length(data);
bucket_labels = randi(3,[1,num_data]); % draw a bucket label for each item, independently.
for i=1:3
  bucket{i} = data(bucket_labels==i,:); 
end

%if your data items are scalars say data = [1 2 3 4 5]    
num_data = length(data);
bucket_labels = randi(3,[1,num_data]);
for i=1:3
  bucket{i} = data(bucket_labels==i); 
end
```

there we go.

Comment: is it possible you could explain the logic behind following lines in the first solution bucket_labels = randi(3,[1,num_data]); Thanks,

Comment: It takes a matrix with shape [1,num_data], (that is a num_data long vector), and fills it up with independently drawn random numbers, with uniform distribution on the set {1, 2, 3}.